# An array of objects as well as their subclasses in Java

Tags: java, arrays, subclass

I am trying to figure out how to define an array of a certain type of objects that will include the subclasses as well. This is what I have :

```
Property[] list = new Property[100];
```

I believe this will define an array of 100 properties, but is it possible for this array to include SubProperty as well. SupProperty is an extension of the Property class.

Thanks very much.

Comment: what kind of subproperty

Comment: It can include `SubProperty` as well, but while retreiving, you'll have to cast it as `SubProperty sub = (SubProperty) list[10]`. Assuming, `list[10]` is an instance of `SubProperty` and not `Property`

Comment: what problem you are facing..?

Comment: Read - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible for the array to include the `SubProperty` as well. Please find the code below -

```
class SubProperty extends Properties{
}
```

and

```
Properties[] obj = new Properties[100];
obj[1] = new SubProperty();
```

you can get back your Object, like -

```
for(Properties prop: obj){
    if(prop instanceof SubProperty){
        SubProperty subProp = (SubProperty)prop;
        System.out.println(subProp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
Animal[] list = new Animal[100]
```

Would you be able to add a `Dog` to that array?, If a `Dog` is an animal, you will be able to do `Animal dog = new Dog();` That's what inheritance is, if you want to know more about it go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. A `SubProperty` object *is* a `Property` object. You can always swap a subclass for its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subclass wherever its superclass can be used. This is OOP substitution principle. It also applies in this situation.